# How to redefine type for an existing function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Solution here https://www.albertgao.xyz/2016/08/11/how-to-declare-a-function-type-variable-in-typescript/ requires to define an expression, that's not what I want. What I want is to declare existing function as any something like this except syntax is not valid:

```
function f() {} as any;
f.someProperty = "I want to do this without squizzle in vscode";
```

goal is to avoid squizzle in VScode.

Comment: Don't think this is possible if you want to avoid everything that isn't a function definition and everything has to stay in one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
const f = function () {} as any;
f.someProperty;
```

From the comments by the asker:

> I wanted to avoid function expression but seems I have to because const f doesn't hoist.